# Running a custom script when StrongSwan connection is established

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, linux-networking, strongswan

I have StrongSwan VPN server set up on a Debian host, and would like to run a custom script when a client connects to it. The only thing I have come up with is periodically checking the contents of the log file, but that seems clunky.

Is there any way to specify a script to execute upon connection, preferably with some way to infer the originating IP and login information used for that connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `leftupdown` or `rightupdown` parameter(s) in [connection section](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConnSection). These will run a script specified as a parameter every time a connection changes state:

```
left|rightupdown = <path>

  what updown script to run to adjust routing and/or firewalling when the status
  of the connection changes (default ipsec _updown).
```

There are some environment variables which give you at least the login information for the connection changing state, for example `$PLUTO_PEER` gives you peer IP. For more about available environment variables, see [`man 8 pluto`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ipsec_pluto) (or `man 8 ipsec_pluto`).

Comment: It's worth noting that the script specified will run *instead* of the default one, not in addition to it. So if you'd like to add something to the default script, make a copy of it, change it to your liking, and point `leftupdown` parameter to it :)